# Confusion about lambda/mean of Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I have some general confusion about what exactly it is. Say you have a period of 24 hours where 100.000 people are tested for covid. Of these 100 test positive. Is lambda then 100/100.000 or simply 100? And why?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter signifies the average rate that events occur in some fixed time interval, in the same units of the random variable.  So if $X$ is Poisson($\lambda$) and represents the number of people who take a COVID test in 24 hours, and if there are 100,000 people who take the test on average in 24 hours, then $\lambda=100,000.$

Comment: In that case if X is Poisson(λ) and represents the number of people who test positive for COVID in 24 hours, then it is the average rate which is 100/100.000 right?

Comment: No.  $X$ and $\lambda$ must be in the same units. Number of people testing positive is not in the same units as fraction of positive tests. The fraction of positive tests cannot be Poisson since a Poisson random variable's support is 0,1,2,...  The number of people testing positive is likely also not well modelled by a Poisson random variable.  A Poisson model is justified under specific assumptions in modelling number of events in a fixed interval of time, including that two events cannot occur at the same time and events occur independently, among others. See wiki:

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution